# Getting error in Chef-ERROR: shard_seed: Failed to get dmi property serial_number: is dmidecode installed?

Tags: linux, chef-infra

I am getting error while running a code in chef

chef-client -zr "recipe[test-cookbook::test-recipe1]"

[2020-08-05T16:01:06+00:00] WARN: No config file found or specified on command line. Using command line options instead.
Starting Chef Infra Client, version 16.3.45
[2020-08-05T16:01:08+00:00] ERROR: shard_seed: Failed to get dmi property serial_number: is dmidecode installed?
resolving cookbooks for run list: ["test-cookbook::test-recipe1"]
Synchronizing Cookbooks:

- test-cookbook (0.1.0)
  Installing Cookbook Gems:
  Compiling Cookbooks...
  Converging 0 resources

Running handlers:
Running handlers complete
Chef Infra Client finished, 0/0 resources updated in 01 seconds

Comment: Please add some details about the operating system you are running this on. However, Chef collects information about the system using [ohai](https://docs.chef.io/ohai/). One of the sources of this information is a command called `dmidecode`. Please check if it is installed.

Answer (score 0):

the error you are getting is because of the code you put in that file,
remove # before everyline of code you put,
plus install dmidecode by putting the command -
sudo yum install dmidecode